# Failed Deploy .Net Core 2.2 Web to NGINX Centos 7

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, centos, reverse-proxy

This is my first time deploying Netcore 2.2 Web App to Linux Centos 7 with NGINX.

i have seen a lot of tutorial like :

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2

and this is my configuration

1. configuration /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf : 
   [image]
2. validate configuration and it's running
   [image]
3. since it's just test i run my web using dotnet [FILE].dll
   [image]
4. my web has run on port 5000
   [image]
5. when i check on port 80 it return 502 Bad Gateway
   [image]

i dont understand where the problem happen ? can anyone help me ?

also in microsoft official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2) there is a code like this :

```
 app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

i don't understand what that code use for ? do i have to add that line of code to my web code to work with reverse proxy ?

Thank You

Comment: When you host your app without a reverse proxy the Kestrel receives all the information it needs, but when there is a reverse proxy in between, some information are lost, because the reverse proxy does not hand them to Kestrel. Like client IP address, or the original schema (http/https). That is what the `ForwardedHeader` do. It receives some additional information from the reverse proxy. `XForwardedFor` is for client IP address, and `XForwardedProto` is for schema. I really don't know what is your problem but I know that you have to make sure this middleware is placed before MVC.

Comment: yes , you have to add app.UseForwardedHeaders in your startup (to answer your question))